# C# scope and values inside using and {} braces

Tags: c#

When use the Using statement and the {} Scope modifier, how do you get a value outside of it? This feels like an anonymous function in procedural code but it's not.

```
using (SqlConnection m_DBCon = new Something())
{
    int x = 1;
}

{
    int y = 3;
}

x; // not found
y; // not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare the variable you need *before* the using block, and then assign it inside.

```
int x;

using (SqlConnection m_DBCon = new Something())
{
    x = 1;
}

// x == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use:

```
int x, y;
using (SqlConnection m_DBCon = new Something())
{
    x = 1;
}

{
    y = 3;
}

// x = 1, y = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the variables before your using block, then access them inside.

```
int x;
int y;
using (SqlConnection m_DBCon = new Something())
{
    x = 1;
}

{
    y = 3;
}

x; 
y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the scope of the variables.  (And probably initialize them too.)

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
using (SqlConnection m_DBCon = new Something())
{
    x = 1;
}
{
    y = 3;
}
```